# Beginner Git Question: Does push update the remote branch to equal the local branch?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I am very new to git, and very confused. Note that I am using a gui (gitKraken) because I was getting even more perplexed by the command line.

I squashed two commits then pushed, expecting the remote branch to update to reflect this. I ended up with my local and remote branch looking like they merged, ie, it wasn't linear. Can someone please explain how I should've gone about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Gitkraken. But I do know that if you squash two commits, and one of them was already pushed, now you cannot push at all, because now the remote has a commit that you don't have (you squashed it). Therefore the only way to proceed is to pull (meaning merge) the remote branch before pushing. Maybe Gitkraken is smart enough to know that so it did that?

So if that's what happened, the takeaway message for you would be: Don't try to rewrite history that you've already pushed. It will end badly.

Comment: So once I commit something, I should never try to modify it? In other words, I should have squashed the commits before committing? What if I notice a mistake in a commit? I take it I would need to make another commit fixing this change?

Comment: "In other words, I should have squashed the commits before committing" You should have squashed the commits before _pushing_.

Comment: "What if I notice a mistake in a commit? I take it I would need to make another commit fixing this change?" Again, that depends whether you've pushed it or not. If you haven't, there are lots of possibilities. But we have now strayed way outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I understand now :)

Comment: @Chessnut: or, in short (too short in some cases but pretty good generally): *push* = *publish*. Now that *other people* have your commits, you can't take them back. (Sometimes you can, depending on who those "other people" are and how much you trust them, which is why this is too short in some cases.)